# Fact=fact*c ?? How does that work? (Factorial Java)

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, factorial

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Factorial {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int n, c, fact = 1;

  System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate it's factorial");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  n = in.nextInt();

  if ( n < 0 )
     System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
  else
  {
     for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
        fact = fact*c; 

     System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
  }
 }
}
```

For this code for finding the factorial of a number, I don't get the part where it says, "fact=fact*c".
I know it's because fact gets "updated" with a new multiplication factor of c, but do the numbers multiply?

**Example: n=3 and c=1,2,3 and fact=1.. then would the process look like, (1*1) * (1*2) * (1*3)= 6?**

Comment: What do you mean, "do the numbers multiply"?

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger you would be able to see what each line of code does.

Comment: (Sneaky tip: `fact *= c`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
fact = fact * c;
```

multiplies `fact` by `c` and stores the result in `fact`.

Thus the following happens when the code is run:

- At the start , `fact` is `1`.
- On the first iteration it gets multiplied by `1` the result of which is `1`.
- On the second iteration it gets multiplied by `2` and becomes `2`.
- On the third iteration it gets multiplied by `3` and becomes `6`.
- On the fourth iteration it gets multiplied by `4` and becomes `24`.

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are right it works like this:

```
fact is 1 initially

loop when c = 1:
multiply c with fact i.e. 1 * 1
store the result back in fact i.e. fact = 1

loop when c = 2
multiply c with fact i.e. 1 * 2
store the result back in fact i.e. fact = 2

loop when c = 3
multiply c with fact i.e. 2 * 3
store the result back in fact i.e. fact = 6
```